# CSS on Blogger.com behaves/aligns differently when viewed in Chromium and Firefox/Opera

Tags: html, css, firefox, blogger, chromium

I use custom CSS on my blogger site. When the CSS regards only one post, I use the CSS code within the post itself. For example, I use it to align the lines of a poem with a graphic background. Since I use Chromium (in Linux Mint 18.1), I use this browser to check the results. However, when I view the same published post in Firefox, the CSS alignment is off.

EDIT: checked Opera as well, behaves the same as Firefox (i.e. Firefox and opera render the text the same way, but differently than Chrome/Chromium).

Anyone who has the two (or more) browsers installed can [check out the post](http://asylum4thoughts.blogspot.com/2015/11/final-day-act-one.html) in both.

The whole post code is as follows:

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">
<div class="image">
<br /></div>
<div class="image">
<a href="http://tsairi.deviantart.com/art/The-Birds-437529362" target="_blank"><img alt="the birds by tsairi final day poem by mozzribo" height="1808" src="https://i.imgur.com/hC2zfVe.png" title="The Birds by Tsairi − click for image source" width="434" /></a>
<br />
<div class="text">
<span style="color: white;">
A seraph approached me last night<br />
Gave me a burning letter and flew away blazing<br />
As I broke the wax stamp a black phoenix fluttered before me<br />
It took me to the fractal spiral and shattered my body<br />
And with it all of my self-proclaimed sins<br />
The eternity that is to be was one and I was told that<br />
There is nothing to regret and there will never be<br />
If I should go through this scabrous wildwood again<br />
I would, just to live again that night when we met at the cemetery<br />
The bird sent me back to believe that there is nothing to regret<br />
Aye, there is nothing to regret<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
When the time comes for gentlemen Their ethics to deprave<br />
I’ll be standing in front of my children’s grave<br />
I’ll be asking with a brain gone illogically brave<br />
Where is my promised final day<br />
That has been taken from the grievous away<br />
Who will kindly grant it to me<br />
Where are the pages of Genesis Lost<br />
And who will pay the cost<br />
Where is my promised final day<br />
That has been taken from the grievous away<br />
Who will kindly grant it to me<br />
Where are the pages of Genesis Lost<br />
And who will pay the cost<br />
Better than my noose in the company of I to be tossed<br />
I to be tossed<br />
Who will kindly stand in front of me and say<br />
"There is still a cigarette to finish in the ashtray."<br />
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.image {
position:relative;
float:center; /* optional */
}
.image .text {
position:absolute;
color: black;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
font-size: 11pt;
top:10px; /* in conjunction with left property, decides the text position */
margin-top:650px;
left:39px;
width:783px; /* optional, though better have one */
}
</style><br /></div>
```

I found what seems to be causing the issue in the following answer:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14324/font-displays-differently-in-firefox-vs-chrome/14347#14347

Yet I do not know if this can be resolved at all. Is there a way to force a browser to render text like the other?

Any suggestions on how can I make the CSS behave the same across all browsers?

Answer (score -1):

clean your browser cache first and update the browser I check your link its working fine in both browsers chrome and firefox good in both. and why you use those br tags over and over just apply margin-top and your good to go

Comment: Thank You, Akshay. I did as You suggested, but the result is the same. I checked from another computer, and the problem persists. Here are the screenshots: [Chromium CSS behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEMkQ.png) and [Firefox CSS behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaLvd.png).

Also thanks for the margin-top tip, I will re-write the code soon, perhaps that helps. I'll comment here about the results.

Comment: its cross browser issue since I can't test your code I can't help

Comment: Thank You for your time in any case. I updated the code with the margin-top. Now the situation is a bit better, but still not the same.

I found the reason in another answer, I added it to my question. Firefox renders the fonts to be a bit bigger.